Conditions for regularity in a covering
Let $V$ be a DVR of mixed characteristic, whose residue field is a finite field of characteristic $2$. Let $R$ be a flat, finitely generated algebra over $V$, which is regular. Let $a\in R^*$ be an invertible element of $R$ and consider the ring $L:=R[t]/\langle t^2-a\rangle$.
Are there conditions which ensure that $L$ is a regular ring? I think that sometimes $L$ is indeed regular but I do not know how general this phenomenon is.
